# Why am I getting an "unrecognized selector sent to class" error for CIFilter?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad-2, cifilter

This code works on an iPad 2 simulator, but not on my physical iPad 2 (which is running on iOS 7.0.6):

```
var fade = CIFilter(name: "CIExposureAdjust", withInputParameters:["inputEV" : -2.0 ])
```

The full error message says:

> [CIFilter filterWithName:withInputParameters:]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to class 0x392d8d9c 2015-07-05 23:12:37.106  *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '+[CIFilter filterWithName:withInputParameters:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to class 0x392d8d9c'

Comment: Read [the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CIFilter/filterWithName:withInputParameters:): 
`+filterWithName:withInputParameters:` -> `Available in iOS 8.0 and later`.

Comment: Darn they got me. that was the first thing I checked, but I just saw the class was "Available in iOS 5.0 and later ".  Didn't think to check the function. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [the official documentation of `+ filterWithName:withInputParameters:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CIFilter/filterWithName:withInputParameters:)

> `+ filterWithName:withInputParameters:`
>
> **Availability**
>   Available in iOS 8.0 and later.

Since your iPad is running on iOS 7, this method is not available, and therefore your app crashes.

A few possible solutions:

1. Use [`- respondsToSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/respondsToSelector:) to check if the method exists.
2. Check if the current foundation version number, [`NSFoundationVersionNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Foundation_Version_Number) is higher than `NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1`.
3. Make iOS 8 a minimum requirement for your app.